# How do you know what methods an object has

Tags: javascript

How do I find out what methods an object has, for example XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Since you've found the account name changing field, would you mind changing to something intelligible? Garbled usernames make it harder for you to get an answer.

Comment: This seems like a valid question that I am also wondering the answer to. For example, in Python there is a dir() function which is quite useful.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252406/given-an-arbitrary-javascript-object-how-can-i-find-its-methods

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
for ( method in yourObject ){
 document.write(method + '<br>');
}
```

or similar. Some browsers are hiding methods of objects...

Answer (score 2):

```
function getFunctions(obj) {
    var funcs = [];
    for (var i in obj)
        if (typeof(obj[i]) == "function")
            funcs.push(i);
    return funcs;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest).

Answer (score 0):

1) Language Documentation

2) Google

3) IDE Autocomplete