# How to get an object's methods?

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, get

Is there a method or propertie to get all methods from an object? For example:

```
function foo() {}
foo.prototype.a = function() {}
foo.prototype.b = function() {}

foo.get_methods(); // returns ['a', 'b'];
```

UPDATE: Are there any method like that in Jquery?

Thank you.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252406/given-an-arbitrary-javascript-object-how-can-i-find-its-methods

Answer (score 78):

```
function getMethods(obj)
{
    var res = [];
    for(var m in obj) {
        if(typeof obj[m] == "function") {
            res.push(m)
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: The `for..in` way is the standard approach.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, Chris! I think you like TypeErrors… `TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating 'obj(m)')`

Comment: Code is now fixed with square brackets. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Added sorting the array for convenience.

Comment: is there a difference if you evaluate the condition `m instanceof Function`?

Comment: This only lists properties

Answer (score 48):

Remember that technically javascript objects don't have methods.  They have properties, some of which may be function objects.  That means that you can enumerate the methods in an object just like you can enumerate the properties.  This (or something close to this) should work:

```
var bar
for (bar in foo)
{
    console.log("Foo has property " + bar);
}
```

There are complications to this because some properties of objects aren't enumerable so you won't be able to find *every* function on the object.

Comment: maybe he was talking about console.log. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I don't do JS every day so I'm not 100% up on it.  But I do understand the language..

Answer (score 27):

You can use `console.dir(object)` to write that objects properties to the console.

Answer (score 19):

In modern browsers you can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff688126%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) to get all properties (both enumerable and non-enumerable) on an object. For instance:

```js
function Person ( age, name ) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function () {
    return "My name is " + this.name;
};

Person.prototype.age = function () {
    this.age = this.age + 1;
};

// ["constructor", "greet", "age"]
Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Person.prototype );
```

Note that this only retrieves *own-properties*, so it will not return properties found elsewhere on the prototype chain. That, however, doesn't appear to be your request so I will assume this approach is sufficient.

If you would only like to see *enumerable* properties, you can instead use [`Object.keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff688127%28v=vs.94%29.aspx). This would return the same collection, minus the non-enumerable `constructor` property.

Answer (score 8):

for me, the only reliable way to get the methods of the final extending class, was to do like this:

```
function getMethodsOf(obj){
  const methods = {}
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) ).forEach(methodName => {
    methods[methodName] = obj[methodName]
  })
  return methods
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The methods can be inspected in the prototype chain of the object using the browser's developer tools (F12):

```
  console.log(yourJSObject);
```

or more directly

```
  console.dir(yourJSObject.__proto__);
```

Answer (score 5):

In ES6:

```
let myObj   = {myFn : function() {}, tamato: true};
let allKeys = Object.keys(myObj);
let fnKeys  = allKeys.filter(key => typeof myObj[key] == 'function');
console.log(fnKeys);
// output: ["myFn"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var funcs = []
for(var name in myObject) {
    if(typeof myObject[name] === 'function') {
        funcs.push(name)
    }
}
```

I'm on a phone with no semi colons :) but that is the general idea.

Comment: What phone has no semi-colons but lets you answer questions?  LOL

Comment: I think a new phone is _colon_ your name!

Answer (score 1):

```
var methods = [];
for (var key in foo.prototype) {
    if (typeof foo.prototype[key] === "function") {
         methods.push(key);
    }
}
```

You can simply loop over the prototype of a constructor and extract all methods.

Comment: This won't account for methods directly attached to the object

Comment: @MattGreer his example called a method on a constructor. Whether he wants methods from a constructor or an object is a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

the best way is:

```
let methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(yourobject);
console.log(methods)
```

use 'let' only in es6,  use 'var' instead

Comment: It returns a list of the attributes.

Comment: As Ali alluded, this excludes functions defined as getters/setters on a class (methods).

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome is `keys(foo.prototype)`. Returns `["a", "b"]`.

See: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#keysobject[image]

Later edit: If you need to copy it quick (for bigger objects), do `copy(keys(foo.prototype))` and you will have it in the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Method Names:

```
var getMethodNames = function (obj) {
    return (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).filter(function (key) {
        return obj[key] && (typeof obj[key] === "function");
    }));
};
```

Or, Get the Methods:

```
var getMethods     = function (obj) {
    return (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).filter(function (key) {
        return obj[key] && (typeof obj[key] === "function");
    })).map(function (key) {
        return obj[key];
    });
};
```