# List built in JavaScript standard object methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, rhino

Is there a way to list all JavaScript standard object method?

I mean I'm trying to get all the built in methods of String so I was thinking and I did tried doing this:

```
for( var method in String ) {
    console.log( method );
}

// I also tried this:
for( var method in String.prototype ) {
    console.log( method );
}
```

But no luck. Also if there is a way that solution should work for all ECMAScript standard classes/objects.

Edit:
I want to point out that the solution should work in server side environment also like rhino or node.js.

And as much as possible not using a third party API/framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/152573/875127

Comment: @CiananSims I think maybe not since this is more on built in classes. The answer there will not work for this question.

Comment: I see. Does http://stackoverflow.com/q/2257993/875127 shed any light? Looks to be a surprisingly non-trivial question.

Comment: @CiananSims I think that one shed a light actually. I look into his answer. And it works! Thanks!


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-in-a-javascript-object/2946616#2946616

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Won't **[dir](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#dirobject)** give you what you need?

```
console.log(dir(method))
```

EDIT:

This would work  (try [John Resig's Blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/) for more info):

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype)` gives :

```
["constructor", "toString", "toLocaleString", "valueOf", "hasOwnProperty", "isPrototypeOf", "propertyIsEnumerable", "__defineGetter__", "__lookupGetter__", "__defineSetter__", "__lookupSetter__"]
```

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object)` gives :

```
["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype", "keys", "create", "defineProperty", "defineProperties", "freeze", "getPrototypeOf", "getOwnPropertyDescriptor", "getOwnPropertyNames", "is", "isExtensible", "isFrozen", "isSealed", "preventExtensions", "seal"]
```

Comment: The method dir returns undefined. What I was thinking is like a function or some sort of procedure that will return an array of built in methods.

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(function () {}).indexOf('bind') //> -1` The autocompleter of node however picks up on the `bind` for find so there must be a way to get _all_ methods of an object. Unless there is adhoc code for specific objects in the completer but I would find that a strange design decision.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the list of methods by checking the type of properties as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842654/javascript-get-objects-methods)

Also try [getOwnPropertyNames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-in-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Yeah my example and the answer there is similar. I just have to add a condition for testing if it is a function or not but as far as I observed it will not work also.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from this post [How to display all methods of an object in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-in-a-javascript-object/2946616#2946616)

Thanks to [CiannanSims](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875127/cianan-sims)

Answer (score 0):

So here is a way to squeeze out a few more properties:

```
> function a () {}
undefined
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)
[ 'length',
  'name',
  'arguments',
  'caller',
  'prototype' ]
> a.bind
[Function: bind]
> // Oops, I wanted that aswell
undefined
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(a))
[ 'length',
  'name',
  'arguments',
  'caller',
  'constructor',
  'bind',
  'toString',
  'call',
  'apply' ]
```

I am not a javascript person but I would guess that the reason that this happens is because `bind`, `toString`, `call` and `apply` might be inherited from higher inheritance levels (does that even make sense in this context?)

EDIT: Btw here is one i implemented that looks as far back in the prototypes as it can.

```
function getAttrs(obj) {
    var ret = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
    while (true) {
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
        try {
            var arr = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
        } catch (e) {
            break;
        }

        for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if (ret.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1)
                ret.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```