# How to assign the functionalities of an existing button to a new button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am writing a Javascript pluggin where I am trying to get all the methods of an existing button on a website and assign it to a button I created myself and delete/hide the old button, so that the Website still works as expected, but with a new button-layout.

**Is there a way to assign the functionalities of an existing button to a new one in Javascript?**

I do not just want to change the layout of the existing button, because later I want to be able to assign functionalities from two existing buttons to a single newly created button.

I am trying to get the methods of the button I want to hide with the following function from:

[How to get an object's methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842654/how-to-get-an-objects-methods)

```
function getMethods(obj)
{
    var res = [];
    for(var m in obj) {
        if(typeof obj[m] == "function") {
            res.push(m)
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/clone/ `withDataAndEvents = true`

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke `click` manually on the old button to cause its listeners to fire. Try something like:

```
// retrieve the button you want to replace
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const newButton = document.createElement('button');
button.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newButton);
// Hide old button
button.style.display = 'none';
newButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // add additional functionality here

  // Run click listeners on old button
  button.click();
});
```