# How to find the interface of a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, defined

For example; the function `alert` or `writeln`; how could I find which interface these functions come from programmatically within JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252406/given-an-arbitrary-javascript-object-how-can-i-find-its-methods

Comment: @StuartKershaw: The question is confusing, but the one you linked to is no good: The OP wants to know where to find a function, not what functions are in an object. (OP asked "is there a reverse", easy to miss I know)

Comment: firebug and code editor has similar features.

Comment: I don't think javascript internally supports this. Ctags also has similar features which you can use, but it is also an external tool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like this:

```
if (typeof(yourFunction) !== "undefined") { 
    // do something, like call the function
}
```

Comment: OP wants to know where to find a function, not whether or not it is defined. There's no good answer unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification -  I misread the question. However, depending on usage, just being able to check if it's defined may solve the problem. Presumably the reason for checking where it's defined is to determine whether it can be called on a certain object. This would fill that need. If the need is different, in my opinion more context is needed to find the best solution (since, like you said, it's not straightforward to find out *where* a js function defined).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check to see that a function *is* defined with `typeof`:

```
if (typeof(maybeFunction) === "function") {
    // do something
}
```

On the other hand, it is not easy in general to know where a function is defined. Different browsers host their core functional implementations in different places, and furthermore it is incredibly easy to copy references to functions:

```
var myAlert = alert;    // Now myAlert is a function,
// but where will you find a function myAlert() declaration? Nowhere...
```

So I think the proper answer to your question is, it's not possible (in general). You can use a debugger to find it on the fly, or a good text editor or grep tool to find it offline, but you won't be able to find it programatically.

Comment: *typeof* is an operator, there is no need to enclose the argument in brackets.

Comment: @RobG: I know. It's a personal style thing-- I like it better with parentheses. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "list an objects functions", you can do:

```
function listOwnMethods(obj) {
  var ownMethods = [];

  for (var p in obj) {

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && typeof obj[p] == 'function') {
      ownMethods.push(p);
    }  
  }
  return ownMethods;
}
```

However, this will not list the non–enumerable properties. If you want to also get enumerable inherited methods, remove the *hasOwnProperty* test.

Some versions of JavaScript also have getters and setters, so properties may behave like functions even though their Type is not "function". Finally, host objects can return anything they like when tested with *typeof*, so you may not be able to determine all (or even any) of a host object's methods that way.